# How would I remove duplicates from an Arraylist<Integer[]>? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

Question says it all really. I tried using a LinkedHashSet but that did not work. If im not wrong, the comparisons were not being done correctly due to the fact that it was comparing Integer arrays.

My aim is to create a static method removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer>). The method should compare based on content of the arrays. My attempt so far:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer[] array1 = new Integer[2];
        array1[0] = 1;
        array1[1] = 4;

        Integer[] array2 = new Integer[2];
        array2[0] = 1;
        array2[1] = 4;

        arrayList.add(array1);
        arrayList.add(array2);

        LinkedHashSet<Integer[]> hashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(arrayList);

        ArrayList<Integer[]> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(hashSet);

        System.out.println("Number of elements before using linkedhashset: " + arrayList.size());
        System.out.println("number of elements after: (expecting 1) " + listWithoutDuplicates.size());
    }
}
```

gives the result:

```
Number of elements before using linkedhashset: 2
number of elements after (expecting 1):  2
```

Comment: It is nice to show add your attempts to solve the problem and some test cases.

Comment: @MajedBadawi I have added my attempt so far with a basic test case

Comment: what is the requirement, do you want to check array content, how much the data should it hold, is it int only or object?

Comment: @silentsudo I want to check array content and order. I have amended the question accordingly

Comment: Is migrating your code from `ArrayList<Integer[]>` to `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` an option?

Comment: @RudraMutalik What Nikolai Shevchenko says. Mixing `List`s and arrays not always work well together. I would recommend to use `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following approach

```
List<Integer[]> listWithoutDuplicates = arrayList.stream()
            .map(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr))
            .distinct()
            .map(list -> list.toArray(new Integer[0]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The trick here is that mapping `Integer[]` to `List<Integer>` allows you to utilize `List::equals()` method that can detect if two Lists are equal (= "both contain same elements in same order"). In conjunction with `Stream::distinct()` that will cut off duplicates, and then every unique `List` is converted back to `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be saving the number of occurrences of each number in each array in the list to consider duplicate numbers, and check whether this instance was already added or not:

```
private static List<Integer[]> removeDuplicates(List<Integer[]> list) {
        List<HashMap<Integer,Integer>> instances = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer[] arr : list) {
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(Integer num : arr) {
                if(map.containsKey(num))
                    map.replace(num, map.get(num)+1);
                else
                    map.put(num,1);
            }
            if(!instances.contains(map)) {
                instances.add(map);
                res.add(arr);
            }
        }
        return res;
}
```

Comment: `if (list == null)` ← Please don’t ever do this.  `null` should never be treated as identical to an empty collection.  If someone wants to pass an empty List, they should pass an empty List.  `null` is a missing value, and usually represents a program error.